# How to form String Using pixel Array and read all characters value of array

Tags: java, arduino, processing, serial-communication

I am Creating a binary image from processing ide. 
 i want to use pixel array as a string . 
when i convert this pixel array to string i can't read String characters. every time i get an error. array index of bound.
please help to out of this problem

```
      for(int y = 0; y < img.height; y++)
       {
         for(int x=0; x < img.width; x++)
          {
                 int i = x+y*img.width;

                 String s = str(i);

                int c = s.charAt(1);

               print(c);
           }
        }
```

when i run this code in processing software i get an error in console that 
  String Index out of Bound ..

please tell me what i  do.

Comment: Why are you using a string?

Comment: i am trying to create binary digit image. and this binary image i  want to formatting in String and get image width and height in String and send this image width like a row wise to arduino.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `s.charAt(0)`: string indices are zero-based.

Comment: yes this works but i want to break line after 100 character. and i can't get the value of this characters in this String.

Comment: try to add `if ((i+1)%100 == 0) print('\n');` after `print(c);`

Comment: StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 1

Comment: @The_nish Yes: use 0, not 1!

Comment: Maurice Perry  in that code line is break after 100 character but my string still is in continous state and print 0 - 10000 character serial. i want to print 100 character at each time . please help me one more time