# Integer pixel array to bit packed String from processing to ardunio

Tags: arduino, processing, serial-communication

I have a led strip with 100 leds connected to an Arduino. I want to use the processing programming language to create a binary image from a png image. 1 for black pixels and 0 for the other. I want the binary image to be equal to the original image. This binary image is to be send to the arduino row by row. This because I use `readString` and not `readByte` in my arduino code.

The problem occurs because the binary image consists of 10000 integer ones and zeroes. I want to pack these into bigger messages wherein 8 pixels each take up one bit in one byte. I then want to sent these packed bytes to my arduino as to be more efficient.

I really want to use the arduino String to contain my rows of data.

Comment: please rewrite your question. it is hard to understand right now. Also how is this question different from you [older question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56765632/how-to-send-100-digit-in-serial-communication-from-processing-to-arduino) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56752110/how-to-form-string-using-pixel-array-and-read-all-characters-value-of-array) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56687015/how-to-write-data-row-wise-in-serial-communication) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56627701/serial-communication-using-int-value-or-string-value)

Comment: please read full artical and understand it . and please help me getting out of this problem

Answer (score 0):

Below is some Arduino (C++) code which packs the one and zero characters contained inside the input `String` into the output `String`. It does this by pushing a new character into the output `String` for every 8 units that have passed and OR-ing a `0x01` at the right place when the current character in the input `String` is `'1'`.

```
String packPixels(String input) {
    String out;
    for(int i=0; i<input.length; i++) {
        if(i % 8 == 0) { 
            out += 0x00;
        }

        if(input[i] == '1') {
            out[out.length-1] |= 1 << i % 8;
        }

    }

    return out
}
```

(ps this code should be able to be used with minimal effort in processing)

Usage will look like:

```
Serial.write(packPixels(pixels));
```

You should look into [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and the [modulo operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation).

You shouldn't be putting binary data inside a `String`, a `std::vector` is better suited for that and clearly communicates that the contents of the vector are **not** characters but bits.